# length of list containing integers in python

Tags: python

The program takes two positive integers (diagonal and term). What it does is that it prints out the sequence of numbers for diagonal in pascal's triangle. So, you input diagonal and up to what term you want it to return the list of numbers.  I put a restriction on the loop, stopping it when the number is bigger than 100. I want it to return the length of the list containing the numbers smaller than 100.

```
"""
Asks what diagonal and up to what term you want 
to see the sequence for any diagonal of pascal's triangle
"""
import math

diagonal = int(input("What diagonal do you want to see?"))
term = int(input("what term do you wan to see?"))

product= term
for i in range (1,term+1):
    product = math.factorial(i-1 + diagonal-1)/ (math.factorial(diagonal-1) * math.factorial(i-1))
    if product > 100:
        break
    print product
print(len(str(product)))
```

It prints out the length of the inputs, but not the length of the list.
EX) diagonal: 5 ; term: 20
list  that it returns: 1,5,15,35,70
length of the list: 3 (it should be 5)

Answer (score 0):

You are not storing the result into a list, the length of `str(product)` is obviously not correct.

```
product = term
result = []  # here
for i in range (1,term+1):
    product = math.factorial(i-1 + diagonal-1)/ (math.factorial(diagonal-1) * math.factorial(i-1))
    if product > 100:
        break
    result.append(product) # here
print(len(result)) # and here
```